# How to position relatively (overlap) two widgets in flutter on top of each other?

Tags: flutter

how can you overlap 2 widgets in flutter on top of each other.

I tried the stack but it does not work in my case as it does not fill the entire height or calculates correctly how much height it needs.

I just want to have

```
scrollList
[
 firstWidget,
 secondWidget -> relative position of this -32 for example thats all to show on top of 
 firstWidget while still having the necessary height! for the entire list
]
```

I am attaching one illustrative image to better visualise the problem.

The image slider is widget 1, the user options and details location etc are widget two.

[image]

**What I have tried:**\

1. I tried the `stack` without success
2. Tried having a listview with 2 stacks inside again does not work as they use same height space. Second stack had positioned bottom 0, even negative bottom but could not push the scroll down and use the necessary space

Comment: can you include your best effort with minimal widget